# Function not 'exiting' as expected

Tags: c#, umbraco

I've (in Umbraco) a parent node, a child of the parent and a child of the child. All three nodes shared a comment property, it's possible that all 3 nodes will have this property populated or any combination thereof.

Basically I need to know the current node that I'm looking at has this property populated and if not then check the parent and so on recursively up the tree.

So I've written the following method:

```
    public int getRecursiveNodePropertyParent (Node targetNode, string alias)
    {
        //does this node have the property?
        var found = getNodeProperty(targetNode.Id, alias);

        if (found == "")
        {
            Node myparentNode = new Node(targetNode.Parent.Id);
            getRecursiveNodePropertyParent(myparentNode, alias);
        }
        else
        {
            return Int32.Parse(targetNode.Id.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

If the current page that I'm viewing has the property populated then the function works fine but if the current page doesn't have the property but it's parent does then the function doesn't work as expected.

Basically what happens is this:
1) It checks the current page and finds nothing
2) It then recalls the function passing in the parent of the current page
3) It finds the value and hits 'return Int32.Parse(targetNode.Id.ToString());'
4) It then continues checking up the tree * i.e. it then hits the line 'getRecursiveNodePropertyParent(myparentNode, alias);'

- This is what I don't understand as surely when the line 'return Int32.Parse(targetNode.Id.ToString());' should cause the routine to exit and return the correct ID but the code block doesn't exit.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything with the return value of the recursive call. Then execution continues through the function, eventually returning 0. It looks like you want to return it:

```
// ...
if (found == "")
{
    Node myparentNode = new Node(targetNode.Parent.Id);
    return getRecursiveNodePropertyParent(myparentNode, alias);
 // ^^^^^^
}
else
{
    return Int32.Parse(targetNode.Id.ToString());
}
```

You can even get rid of the `return 0;` at the end now, since both branches of the `if-else` return a value.

Comment: same idea as I had :)

Comment: Genius! Thank you my friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not returning in

```
getRecursiveNodePropertyParent(myparentNode, alias);
```

instead it goes on and hits the last line with

return 0;

Maybe you should return the value of the first? I don't know the rest of your code, but maybe that's already it.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco has this functionality out of the box, no need for any additional code.

Assuming you're using V6 or V7 rather than use the Node representation of the content, use IPublishedContent, that has a method called GetPropertyValue that you can tell to recurse up the tree. So for example you can do something like:

```
var propertyValue = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("myAlias", recursive: true);
```

Which will mean that propertyValue will have the value of the content node if it's set, otherwise it'll automatically recurse up the tree for you and look for it.